# Validating Database Input C# Access Oledb

Tags: c#, ado.net, oledb

I am very new to C# and need a little bit of help on validating the input that can be added to the access database before it is inserted.

Most of the validations will be if something has not been entered then a message box will appear saying 'nothing entered' or if something needs more characters then 'length too short'. How could i achieve something like this?

Here is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using ClassLibrary;
using System.Data;

namespace ClassLibrary2
{
    public class Class1
    {
        OleDbConnection connection;
        OleDbCommand command;

        private void ConnectTo()
        {
            connection = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=F:\CMS\CustomerDatabase.accdb;Persist Security Info=False");
            command = connection.CreateCommand();
        }
        public Class1()
        {
            ConnectTo();
        }

        public void Insert(Customer p)
        {
            try
            {
                command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO CustomerData ([Forename], [Surname], [Email Address], [Home Phone Number], [Mobile Phone Number], [Address], [AreaTown], [County], [Postcode]) VALUES('" + p.Forename1 + "', '" + p.Surname1 + "', '" + p.EAddress1 + "', '" + p.HomePhone1 + "' , '" + p.MobNum1 + "' , '" + p.Address1 + "', '" + p.AreaTown1 + "', '" + p.County1 + "', '" + p.Postcode1 + "')";
                command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                connection.Open();

                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw;
            }
            finally
            {
                if (connection != null)
                {
                    connection.Close();
                }
            }
        }

        public List<Customer> FillComboBox()
        {
            List<Customer> CustomersList = new List<Customer>();
            try
            {
                command.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM CustomerData";
                command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                connection.Open();

                OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    Customer p = new Customer();

                    p.Id = Convert.ToInt32(reader["ID"].ToString());
                    p.Forename1 = reader["Forename"].ToString();
                    p.Surname1 = reader["Surname"].ToString();
                    p.EAddress1 = reader["Email Address"].ToString();
                    p.HomePhone1 = reader["Home Phone Number"].ToString();
                    p.MobNum1 = reader["Mobile Phone Number"].ToString();
                    p.Address1 = reader["Address"].ToString();
                    p.AreaTown1 = reader["AreaTown"].ToString();
                    p.County1 = reader["County"].ToString();
                    p.Postcode1 = reader["Postcode"].ToString();

                    CustomersList.Add(p);
                }
                 return CustomersList;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw;
            }
            finally
            {
                if (connection != null)
                {
                    connection.Close();
                }
            }    
        }

        public void Update(Customer oldCustomer, Customer newCustomer)
        {
            try
            {
                command.CommandText = "UPDATE CustomerData SET [Forename] = @newCustomer.Forename1, [Surname] = @newCustomer.Surname1, [Email Address] = @newCustomer.EAddress1, [Home Phone Number]= @newCustomer.HomePhone1, [Mobile Phone Number] = @newCustomer.MobNum1, [Address]= @newCustomer.Address1, [AreaTown] = @newCustomer.AreaTown1, [County]= @newCustomer.County1, [Postcode]= @newCustomer.Postcode1 WHERE [ID] = @oldCustomer.Id";
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Forename", newCustomer.Forename1);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Surname", newCustomer.Surname1);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email Address", newCustomer.EAddress1);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Home Phone Number", newCustomer.HomePhone1);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Mobile Phone Number", newCustomer.MobNum1);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Address", newCustomer.Address1);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AreaTown", newCustomer.AreaTown1);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@County", newCustomer.County1);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Postcode", newCustomer.Postcode1);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", oldCustomer.Id);

                command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                connection.Open();

                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw;
            }
            finally
            {
                 if (connection != null)
                {
                   connection.Close();
                }
            }
        }
```

Thanks for your help, im really struggling

Comment: If you use a .Net version > 3.5 then you can annotate the validation. Is it a web or desktop app?

Comment: it will be a desktop app

Comment: Also, look into parameterized queries.. Even though not web-based, get your start doing it correctly, vs struggling later on.  Even desktop based, you are open for sql-injection.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to archive this try to Implement a function that check every validation before you execute the save function 
hope following sample function will give you an idea

```
      private bool CheckValidation(  )
      {

            bool returnBool = true;

            if ( string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtName.txt) )
            {
                 //Show a label next to you text box

                 returnBool = false;
            }


            return returnBool;

      }
```

If your return value is true save the data to data base using SP
Hope this will guide you. for extra information have you aware with SQLHelper class. It will make your life easier, therefore you don't need to implement connection and SP calls every where. if not let me know will send you sample project.

welcome to .NET world

regards,
Pubudu

Comment: still a bit confused, where do i add these bits of code?

Answer (score 0):

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using ClassLibrary;
using System.Data;

namespace DAL
{
    public static class CustomerDAL
    {
     public static void Insert(Customer p){.......}
     public static List<Customer> FillComboBox(){......}
     public void Update(Customer oldCustomer, Customer newCustomer){.......}
    }
}
----------------------------------------------------
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using ClassLibrary;
using System.Data;

namespace BAL
{
    public class Customer
    {
     public int Id {get;set;}
     public string Name {get;set;}
     .......................
     .......................
    }
}
------------------------------------------------------
In UI Create a Windows or Web Form and add buttons and textbox and on buttonSave_Click event 
If(txtName.Text=="")
{
MessageBox.Show("Some text", "Some title", 
    MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    txtName.Focus();
}
else
{
//calling BAL
var cus=new Customer{
Name=txtName.Text
}
//Calling DAL
CustomerDAL.Insert(cus);
MessageBox.Show("Information", "Record saved successfully inti the database.", 
    MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
    txtName.tex="";

}

Hope this will help you.
```

Create a solution,give it a proper name.Then inside the solution create two assembles projects BAL and DAL.If you are still confused about assembles then avoid creating assemblies and following link might help you.
http://www.tutorialized.com/tutorial/3-Tier-Architecture-in-asp.net-using-c/67931

Answer (score 0):

Validation of user input regarding length, patterns, text versus numbers, etc. should be done before your code gets near the data layer.
This is what regular expressions are great at. There is a ton of information on using them, so I won't try to repeat here. Just bingoogle regular expressions and you will find a wealth of info.